# How to reduce the polling frequency of the w1-gpio module on an Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python-3, ds18b20, 1-wire

I would like to know how to influence the polling frequency of a device on the w1-gpio module.

The reason is because I have a DS18B20 temperature sensor on a Raspi that reads too hot.

The first thing I thought I'd try, is to reduce the frequency of reading it out, as it warms itself up when read out too often. ([Link](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/789/my-ds18b20-is-reading-high-how-can-i-get-it-to-return-the-correct-temperature))

Edit: I have since determined that is is indeed read out continuously, multiple times per second, using monitor.py as was kindly suggested below. From my application, I only read once per 15 seconds.

I have used the code found in various places to read it out. ([Link](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_Tutorial_Series:_1-Wire_DS18B20_Sensor))

I've been unable to find documentation that helps me understand this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell the module provides no mechanism to vary the frequency of polling.

I suspect you are wasting your time in thinking that the  polling rate is an issue in the temperature reading.

I believe the polling rate to be in the tens of seconds.  If you want to find out the exact time then monitor the 1-wire GPIO with something like [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) or run [monitor.py](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py).

The module you linked to is not the official driver.  What makes you think it is relevant to your Raspberry Pi usage?

Comment: Thank you for the useful pointers! To answer your last question: I'm probably looking at the wrong documentation, so I removed that link. However, the polling rate can not be in the tens of seconds as I notice temperature changes when I hold the sensor within seconds.